# What is the problem with how I am creating and populating a NSArray in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d to populate a NSMutable Array, then creating an NSArray from that array.  I do the following code 3 times in a row with different array names, and on the third time Instruments is reporting leaks with each element I add to the array.

The weird thing is, its not on EVERY creation and addition of a CCSprite, and the lines that it complains about are different every time I run the app.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
[tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite];
[tempSprite release];
tempSprite = nil;


tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
[tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite];
[tempSprite release];
tempSprite = nil;

tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
[tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite];
[tempSprite release];
tempSprite = nil;

tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
[tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite];
[tempSprite release]; 
tempSprite = nil;

self.numbersArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempNumberArray];
[tempNumberArray release];
tempNumberArray = nil;
```

Edit: Thanks for taking a look at this.
The first time I use tempSprite I initialize it like:

```
CCSprite * tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
[tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite];
[tempSprite release]; 
tempSprite = nil;
```

I release tempSprite between each allocation because it would be a leak otherwise.      [tempNumberArray addObject:tempSprite] retains the sprite object.

Comment: what's the initialization code for `tempSprite`?

Comment: Why are you releasing your tempSprites? They're not going to be in your array if you've released them.

Comment: @Luke: the array retains the added objects. Releasing the objects, which were created with alloc, is correct in order to not leak when the pointer is reused.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that `[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempNumberArray]` creates an **[autoreleased copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391914/what-does-arraywitharray-actually-do/1392051#1392051)** of the array? (On second thought, probably not, because the `numbersArray` property setter will retain it, right?)

Comment: Yes, the self.numbersArray setter will retain that, correct.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to assign nil to tempSprite before you release the object? Won't that cause it to crash because tempSprite is now a freed object?

Comment: @Dalisto1: No. Setting `tempSprite` to `nil` before calling `release` would cause a leak -- you would lose the reference to the object. The code as written does not cause a crash. The object is released and then the pointer is set to `nil`. This is a perfectly acceptable procedure.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that my problem is elsewhere in my code and Instruments is just reporting it here...thanks for taking a look at this guys.  Any suggestions/comments are still welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're seeing leaks. The code you've posted is correct, although it's not necessary to set `tempSprite` to `nil` every time; you really only need to do this if there is a chance you will use the pointer to try to message the object after releasing it. It doesn't hurt anything, however.

The only improvement I can suggest is to do the array construction in a loop:

```
// You can also use an autoreleased mutable array, since you don't need it
// to stick around after construction.
NSMutableArray * tempNumbersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
int i;
for( i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SPRITES; i++ ){
    CCSprite * tempSprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"0.png"];
    [tempNumbersArray addObject:tempSprite];
    [tempSprite release];
}

self.numbersArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempNumbersArray];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on cleaning up the code by using a for loop.  That makes sense, I think I'll do that!  I'll have to look elsewhere in my code for the error I'm getting.