# Instantiate an NSArray passing a mutable array changes array to mutable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I instantiate an NSArray passing it an NSMutableArray, does it become a NSArray or does it just appear to be one.

i.e. is the mutable array eventually released

```
- (NSArray *)getObjectivesWithPerspective:(Perspective *)perspective
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (ObjectiveManagedObject *objective in self.objectives)
    {
        if (objective.perspective.objectID == perspective.objectID) {
            [result addObject:objective];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some info about this here: [what does -arrayWithArray actually DO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391914/what-does-arraywitharray-actually-do).  But the array you get back should be immutable.  NSArray will copy the references into an immutable array.

If in doubt do a test.  Get an array back from the method, cast it as a NSMutableArray and try to add an object.  You should get an error when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392051/254422

Basically, it copies the objects into a new, autoreleased, immutable NSArray.

The NSMutableArray created using +array is autoreleased.

Comment: You might want to reread the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) -- the rule you stated is incorrect. According to the guide, "You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, `alloc`, `newObject`, or `mutableCopy`)."

Comment: You might want to read the NSArray class reference. 
+arrayWithArray: "Creates and returns an array containing the objects in another given array."
Just because the particular static method +arrayWithArray: does not begin with alloc, new, copy or mutableCopy, does not mean that any underlying code beneath it does not.

Comment: Actually, Objective-C doesn't have static methods; it has class methods which are something quite different. Not sure what relevance you think the `NSArray` class reference has to the naming rules for memory management, but your statement regarding "methods not starting with new/create or init" is flat-out wrong.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were arguing that the NSArray returned from +arrayWithArray: was not a new object just because it wasn't called with alloc, new, copy or mutableCopy. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, you can return `result` directly without the need to create a new `NSArray` object:

```
- (NSArray *)getObjectivesWithPerspective:(Perspective *)perspective
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (ObjectiveManagedObject *objective in self.objectives)
    {
        if (objective.perspective.objectID == perspective.objectID) {
            [result addObject:objective];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```